# GridView Delete Function not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do you delete from the gridview delete?

[image]

I tried this but it does not work?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Groups]" DeleteCommand ="DELETE FROM Groups WHERE GroupID = @GroupID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="GroupID" ControlId="DropDownListID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="GroupName" ControlId="DropDownListID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="Description" ControlId="DropDownListID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />

        </DeleteParameters>
```

Gridview code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView_manageGroup" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="GroupID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupID" HeaderText="Group ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="GroupID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="GroupName" HeaderText="Group Name" SortExpression="GroupName" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already set `DataKeyNames="GroupID"` in `<asp:GridView>` tag

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_manageGroup" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="GroupID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
```

You need to change `<asp:SqlDataSource>` tag to this

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Groups]" DeleteCommand ="DELETE FROM Groups WHERE GroupID = @GroupID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="GroupID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
```

Comment: You are right!Thank you so much.Now my gridview delete the row when i delete it using the gridview

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Groups]" DeleteCommand ="DELETE FROM Groups WHERE GroupID = @GroupID">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter Name="GroupID" ControlId="DropDownListID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />

        </DeleteParameters>
```

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

In aspx

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CssClass="grid-close" CausesValidation="False"
                        CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/Images/DELETE.png" 
                        CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="75px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

In code behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
     try
        {   
            Label lblRequestID =  (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblRequestID");
            Delete(lblRequestID .Text);
            FillGrid();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.InnerException);
        }
    }
```